Applying a log to exponential and linear fitting
I fit some data with or without linearisation transformation.
This should not give the same result as exposed in this question: Differences between approaches to exponential regression . But here, when transforming, I take into account the error propagation by adding weights.
I still get different results. What is wrong?
Here is the code:
# Clear environment
rm(list=ls())


# Generate x values and y values
x_values_exp <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4)  
y_values_exp  <- c(9, 8.5, 7.5, 6.4, 5.2, 4.7, 4.5)
# Create a data frame
my_data <- data.frame(x = x_values_exp, y = y_values_exp)


# Fit the nonlinear model (exp) using unknown weights
mod_exp <- nls(y ~ A * exp(B * x), data = my_data, start = list(A = 1, B = 1))

# Estimate error on mod_exp (2 as I have 2 parameters)
residuals <- residuals(mod_exp)
y_error_estimated <- sqrt(sum(residuals^2)/(length(residuals)-2))
my_data$y_error_estimated <- y_error_estimated


# Apply log
y_lin <- log(y_values_exp)
# I have to calculate the corresponding error on y (using error propagation)
y_lin_errors <- y_error_estimated / y_values_exp
my_data$y_lin_errors <- y_lin_errors


# Fit the linear model (using the transformed data and taking into account the estimated error)
mod_lin<- nls(log(y) ~ A + B * x, data = my_data, start = list(A = 1, B = 1), weights = 1/(y_lin_errors^2))

# Print
log( coef(mod_exp)[1]) # log
coef(mod_lin)[1] # lin

And this gives:
> log( coef(mod_exp)[1]) # log
       A 
2.151668 
> coef(mod_lin)[1] # lin
       A 
2.154402 

Using
y_lin_errors <- y_error_estimated / predict(mod_exp)

as mentioned in the comment (Sextus Empiricus), this gives better results:
> log( coef(mod_exp)[1]) # log
       A 
2.151668 
> coef(mod_lin)[1] # lin
       A 
2.150832 

```


Your title is curious because "linearizing an exponential" is not a linear transformation, nor is it even an equivalent model (because the errors have different distributions).

Indeed. Thanks. I have corrected the title.

"I am then wondering why I get different values for A (2.151668 versus 2.154402)." why did you expect this to be the same? Fitting a transformed data, will lead to a different model.

Also, your example is very verbose, you could reduce it to a few lines. Long names like nlMMERROR_lin_weigths_estimated make if difficult to follow and eventually you just compare two models (there seem to be more somehow)? Just an example with mod1 and mod2 would make it easier to follow.

You have one variation in your modeling by applying weights, but this doesn't change anything because the weights are all the same. Removing this from the example will make it easier to follow.

Here is a related question (or answer to another question that relates to your question). https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/550757/164061

Where is your code making use of the ggplot2 library? I'm pretty sure that's not required anywhere.

Have edited the question accordingly. In both cases I use nls and so https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/550757/164061 does not 'help'.

You could pose the question: "how can I use weights to make fitting an expontial curve with nls and lm return the same fit". That makes it more clearly different.

The code is much more clear now.

I think that for error propagation you should use only the fitted values by the non-linear model. Using the y_values_exp  can be done as estimate but won't work well The situation is similar to glm https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466212/466262#466262 there an itterated algorithm is used. But if you already have the fit from a non-linear fitting method, then you can use those.

Yes. It is much better. Thanks

@whuber. Of course "linearizing an exponential" appears curious at first sight. But strangely this is possible and even more usefull in some cases. An exponential equation can be transformed to a linear integral equation. Several examples of nonlinear regression which are transformed into linear regression are shown in the paper https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales .
