# Confidence interval for the odds ratio in a finite population

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval, odds-ratio, finite-population

Does it make sense to estimate a confidence interval for the odds ratio / logistic regression model when the sample size is nearly equal to population size? For example, if the sample size is 50 and the population size is 60.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no problem with forming a confidence intervals when your sample is near the size of the (finite) population. You typically just need to use the [finite population correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Correction_for_finite_population):
\begin{align}
{\rm finite}\ SE &= SE \times \sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}    \\
 \\
                 &= SE \times\sqrt{\frac{60-50}{60-1}}  \\
 \\
                 &= SE\times.41
\end{align}
In your specific case (i.e., logistic regression), it is worth noting that this would be a Wald confidence interval, and Wald CI's rely on large sample theory.  (There is some relevant discussion here: [Why do my p-values differ between logistic regression output, chi-squared test, and the confidence interval for the OR?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/144608/7290))  Your sample of 50 should probably not be considered large, so the CI will probably not really have the coverage it promises.

Nonetheless, I think a confidence interval would add some legitimate information to help interpret your results, so I might still do it (with the appropriate caveats explicitly noted for readers).