# Wald test explanation

Tags: wald-test

Can someone explain to me what a Wald test is please. I have seen it twice today and cannot figure out what it does (other than test for sig difference like a t-test or chi-square).  What would you use it for, and what makes it the right test to chose? 
Thanks in advance
Cat

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210089/raos-score-lagrange-multiplier-test-most-powerful-when-theta-close-to-thet/210100#210100 this picture tells you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

A Wald test is any statistical test that imposes a restriction (null hypothesis, say, $H_{0}=0$ for t-test test of significance of an estimator) and then tests the validity of this restriction to decide wether to keep a variable/retain the alternative (in the example of the t-test again, $H_{a}\neq 0$). It is one of three classes of statistical tests (see [enter link description here][this paper]’s introduction + more if you’re interested). The three types of tests are classified as: Wald tests, Lagrange Multiplier (LM) tests, and Likelihood Ratio (LR) tests; all have a slightly different approach to testing.

You would likely use Wald tests for deciding wether or not to remove a variable from a regression model. It is perhaps its most used application. Or to decide wether or not to include a quadratic term of a variable in a regression model.