# Logistic regression multivariate : Odds ratio / Wald-test

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, wald-test

I have a small problem with one of my analyses.
I'm doing a multivariate logistic regression so some continuous variables have been discredited by quartiles.
Here are my results:
OR and IC

| Variable | unit | OR | lower limit IC | upper limit IC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Variable A | 20 | 1.3437560 | 1.0814409 | 1.6757319 |
| Variable B first quartile | 1 | 2.0054150 | 0.8881467 | 4.8872483 |
| Variable B second quartile | 1 | 1.2150582 | 0.5014275 | 3.1025704 |
| Variable B third quartile | 1 | 1.4801394 | 0.6200311 | 3.7682139 |
| Variable C first quartile | 1 | 2.5960149 | 1.1427893 | 6.3318406 |
| Variable C second quartile | 1 | 2.7227333 | 1.2000598 | 6.6519756 |
| Variable C third quartile | 1 | 1.9318410 | 0.8255948 | 4.8292896 |
| Variable D | -200 | 1.0308258 | 0.8215131 | 1.3461578 |
| Variable E | -10 | 1.0478705 | 0.8473907 | 1.2948567 |
| Variable F | 1 | 1.0802896 | 0.5128503 | 2.1359383 |

Wald test

| Variable | Df | Chisq | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Variable A | 1 | 7.0270868 | 0.0080286 |
| Variable B | 3 | 3.4891983 | 0.3221658 |
| Variable C | 3 | 6.4613940 | 0.0911975 |
| Variable D | 1 | 0.0573684 | 0.8107047 |
| Variable E | 1 | 0.1876317 | 0.6648951 |
| Variable F | 1 | 0.0455897 | 0.8309234 |

For my variable C, which has been discredited, the confidence interval of the first and second quartile does not include 1 so significant, but my variable C is not significant according to the Wald test. As I understand (With my humble knowledge in statistics) the Wald test in the context of logistic regression is used to determine whether a certain predictor variable  is significant or not. It rejects the null hypothesis of the corresponding coefficient being zero.

How can I interpret this result ? Should I reject the entire variable or just the third quartile?

Comment: Breaking up the predictors into quartiles is [not a good approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/28500). Continuous modeling with restricted cubic splines is much more flexible and allows you to evaluate both the overall significance of the predictor and the significance of the nonlinear terms. If you are interested in prediction, the "statistical significance" of the individual coefficients doesn't really matter, anyway--there's no need to "reject" any variable.

Comment: Related to @EdM's great answer, the use of the term 'discredited' in the OP is very appropriate here.  The result is arbitrary, power-losing, and is completely impossible to interpret for reasons detailed in [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Indeed using a modeling with restricted cubic splines is a good solution. But my thesis master wants us to discredit the non-linear continuous variables (old school I think).

Comment: Thanks for the documentation ;).

Comment: First: Multivariate regression is when you have multiple outcome variables, you probably have multiple regressors, which us *multiple regression*. Please edit/clarify! Then: It is known that Wald tests are not very adequate with logistic regression, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/457851/logistic-regression-wald-statistic