# How does R calculate the p-value for this binomial regression?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, logistic, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

Consider the following binomial regression:

```
# Create some data
set.seed(10)
n <- 500
x <- runif(n,0,100)
y <- x + rnorm(n,sd=100) < 0
 
# Fit a binomial regression model
model <- glm(y ~ x, family="binomial")

summary(model)
```

The `summary` function returns a p-value of `1.03e-05`. When using `anova.glm`, one gets slightly more extreme p-values regardless of what method is used to calculate the p-value.

```
anova(model, test="Rao")   # p.value = 7.5e-6
anova(model, test="LRT")   # p.value = 6.3e-6
anova(model, test="Chisq") # p.value = 6.3e-6
```

Does the p-value from the `summary` function apply to the same hypothesis as the ones returned by the `anova` function? If yes, how did `summary` compute this p-value and is it possible to perform the same computation directly with `anova`?

Comment: Despite the R function taking "binomial" as the argument to family, the default binomial family assumes the logit link, and you are conducting logistic regression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may help you to read my answer here: [Why do my p-values differ between logistic regression output, chi-squared test, and the confidence interval for the OR?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/144608/7290)  Your question here is nearly a duplicate of that, but there are a couple of additional elements in your question that can be addressed.

As @CliffAB notes, the p-values in the `summary.glm()` output are from Wald tests.  These are analogous to $t$-tests of coefficients for a linear model in that they are the difference between the fitted value of the coefficient and the reference value (taken to be $0$), divided by the standard error.  The difference is that these are taken to be distributed as a standard normal instead of $t$.  On the other hand, these are valid for large samples and we don't necessarily know what constitutes a 'large sample' in any given case.

Using `anova.glm()` gives you access to different tests.  When you set `test="Rao"`, it gives you the p-value from a score test.  And when you set either `test="Chisq"` or `test="LRT"` (they are the same), it gives you the p-value from a likelihood ratio test.

The `anova.glm()` function does test the same null hypothesis as the Wald test in the `summary()` output *in this case*.  That is *only* because your model has just one variable.  The `anova.glm()` function will perform sequential tests, which are analogous to 'type I SS' in a linear setting, whereas the Wald tests from `summary()` are analogous to 'type III SS' in a linear setting (see my answer here: [How to interpret type I, type II, and type III ANOVA and MANOVA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20455/7290)).  Consider:

```
x2 = rnorm(n)
m2 = glm(y~x+x2, family="binomial")
summary(m2)$coefficients
#                Estimate  Std. Error    z value     Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept) -0.05906436 0.186876339 -0.3160612 7.519561e-01
# x           -0.01567551 0.003537183 -4.4316372 9.352029e-06
# x2          -0.05967796 0.099093504 -0.6022388 5.470152e-01
anova(m2, test="LRT")
# Terms added sequentially (first to last)
# 
#      Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
# NULL                   499     619.10              
# x     1  20.3841       498     598.72 6.335e-06 ***
# x2    1   0.3627       497     598.35     0.547    
m3 = glm(y~x2+x, family="binomial")  # I just switched the order of x & x2 here
summary(m3)$coefficients
#                Estimate  Std. Error    z value     Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept) -0.05906436 0.186876339 -0.3160612 7.519561e-01
# x2          -0.05967796 0.099093504 -0.6022388 5.470152e-01  # these are the same
# x           -0.01567551 0.003537183 -4.4316372 9.352029e-06  #  as above
anova(m3, test="LRT")
# Terms added sequentially (first to last)
# 
#      Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
# NULL                   499     619.10              
# x2    1   0.1585       498     618.94    0.6906      # these differ from the
# x     1  20.5883       497     598.35 5.694e-06 ***  #  anova output above
```

You can shoehorn the `anova.glm()` function to give you score and likelihood ratio tests of individual variables in a multiple logistic regression model that are analogous to 'type III SS', but it is tedious.  You would need to keep refitting your model so that each variable in turn is listed last in the formula provided to the `glm()` call.  The last p-value listed in the `anova.glm()` output is one that will be analogous to 'type III SS'.

To get the score or likelihood ratio tests of individual variables more conveniently, use `drop1()` instead.  Consider:

```
drop1(m3, test="LRT")
# Single term deletions
# 
# Model:
# y ~ x2 + x
#        Df Deviance    AIC     LRT  Pr(>Chi)    
# <none>      598.35 604.35                      
# x2      1   598.72 602.72  0.3627     0.547      # the same as when x2 is last above
# x       1   618.94 622.94 20.5883 5.694e-06 ***  # the same as when x  is last above
```

Answer (score 7):

In `R`, the `summary` function for `glm` computes the p-value using a simple Wald statistic, i.e.

$2 \times \Phi \left(\frac{-|\hat \beta|} { SE(\hat \beta) } \right)  $

where $\hat \beta$ is the regression parameter of interest, $SE(\hat \beta)$ is the standard error of this estimated regression parameter and $\Phi$ is the CDF of a standard normal distribution.

To recreate this from your output, try

```
 beta = coef(model)[2]
 # getting estimate
 B_SE = sqrt(vcov(model)[2,2])
 # extracting standard error
 pvalue =  pnorm(-abs(beta) / B_SE)  * 2
 # pvalue = 1.027859e-05
```