# Interpretation of p-values in glm() and sjPlot::tab_model() for quasi-poisson regression

Tags: r, quasi-likelihood

I am running a quasi-poisson regression predicting a count outcome from 4 variables of interest.

[image]

I understand that these estimates need to be exponentiated to correctly interpret the results. I used the `tab_model()` command in sjPlot to gather these and noted that the p-value  and associated 95% CI (displayed below) are different from the p-value provided in the `glm()` output (above).

[image]

Could someone please provide any clarification on the discrepancy between these two? Is it typical practice to report the IRR and 95% CI (and possibly whatever this associated p-value is in the `tab_model()` command)?

Comment: After doing a little bit of digging around here, it looks like the p-values from the `glm()` output is derived using Wald tests (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237073/how-does-r-calculate-the-p-value-for-this-binomial-regression). I read that Wald tests may be "valid" for "large samples" but less so in smaller ones, which is arguably not the case in mine (N = 21). Is it reasonable then to report the exponentiated coefficients/CIs and the associated p-values generated via `tab_model()`?