# Comparison of nested regression models vs predictor's significance within model

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, likelihood-ratio, nested-models

I am building regression models to evaluate the effect of several characteristics of genetic variants (my predictors) on a handful of phenotypic parameters (continuous and binary - hence I am building linear and binomial models).
In some cases I am observing that:

- the p-value for the 'slope coefficient' of predictor *Z* within the model is not significant (p-value displayed in the output of the `summary()` function in R

**but**

- when I compare nested models ([*A*~ *X*+*Y*] vs [*A*~ *X*+*Y*+*Z*]) with a likelihood ratio test, the model containing *Z* among predictors has a significantly lower residual deviance than one without *Z*. I do this with the R command:

  ```
  anova(lm(A~X+Y,data=vardata),lm(A~X+Y+Z,data=vardata),test="LRT")
  ```

How should this type of results be interpreted?

In my understanding this means that, when taken into account, predictor *Z* significantly improves the model's performance. However, I would then also expect the coefficient of *Z* in the model to be significantly different from 0.

Comment: For a continuous OLS model, is you leave off the "test=LRT", then the two will be the same. I beleive that you are getting a difference based on different estimation methods.

Comment: Closely related: [Why do my p-values differ between logistic regression output, chi-squared test, and the confidence interval for the OR?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144603/7290)

Comment: @dbwilson, why not turn that into an official answer?