# Why is odds ratio overlapping 1 while Chi-square P value is well below 0.05?

Tags: python, confidence-interval, p-value, chi-squared-test

I have following values from an experiment:

```
   A   B
X 64  20
Y 62  11
```

I subject this to Chi-square test using following code:

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
pval = chisquare([a,b], [c,d])[1]
print(pval)
```

Output is:

```
0.006421123271652286
```

This seems clearly significant (<0.05).

I now calculate odds ratio and its confidence intervals with above data using following formulae:

```
OR = (a*d) / (b*c)
se = math.sqrt((1/a)+(1/b)+(1/c)+(1/d))
lower  = np.exp(math.log(OR) - 1.96*se)
upper  = np.exp(math.log(OR) + 1.96*se)
print(OR, lower, upper)
```

Output is:

```
0.5677  0.2514   1.2819
```

( The confidence intervals agree with online calculator at https://select-statistics.co.uk/calculators/confidence-interval-calculator-odds-ratio/  )

So, confidence interval is very much overlapping 1, while I expected it to be on one side of 1 since P value was clearly significant.

I have following questions:

1. Where is the error and how can I correct it?
2. Would you call these data as statistically significant?
3. What test can I use so that P value and confidence intervals match?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related (even possible duplicate): [Why do my p-values differ between logistic regression output, chi-squared test, and the confidence interval for the OR?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144603/7290)

Comment: There difference is very borderline, here it seems to be marked. Would you call these data as statistically significant?

Comment: Are you sure you are applying the software correctly?  The p-value should be around 24%.  Isn't `chisquare` supposed to be a "one-way chi square test"?

Comment: You were right about underlying incorrect use of software and about real P value (as shown in accepted answer below).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The chisquare function tests given counts against expected counts.  That's not what you intend.  You're testing a contingency table.  Use the chi2_contingency function with takes a table (nested array) as input and returns:

> ```
> chi2: float 
>     The test statistic.
>
> p: float
>     The p-value of the test
>
> dof: int
>     Degrees of freedom
>
> expected: ndarray, same shape as observed
>     The expected frequencies, based on the marginal sums of the table.
> ```

(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html)

The correct analysis gives a p-value of 0.24:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
>>> chi2_contingency([[64,20],[62,11]])
(1.3719790003937939, 0.24147215490328422, 1, array([[ 67.41401274,  16.58598726],
       [ 58.58598726,  14.41401274]]))
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, that was the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from abstrusiosity is of course correct, I just wanted to add that you can also use the `chisq.test()` function in R to calculate the chi-square statistic and it's associated p-value. So, if you have a contingency table (a more-dimensional chi-square test), use the `chisq.test()` function like:

```
x <- matrix(c(64, 62, 20, 11), ncol = 2)

chisq.test(x)
```

Result:

```
X-squared = 1.372, df = 1, p-value = 0.2415
```

Comment: Welcome to Stats.Stackexchange.com. You are correct and R is a more standard language for statistical work than Python.