# What if the P-Value is less than 0.05, but the test statistic is also less than the critical value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, p-value, critical-value

Let's say you let the Null Hypothesis $H_0$ be that the mean volume of water in a bottle is some $\mu$, and the alternate hypothesis $H_1$ be that the mean volume is not $\mu$.

Let's assume you pick a 95% confidence interval, so $\alpha = 0.05$. That would give you a critical value (assuming a normal distribution) of 1.96.

Let's say the P-Value is less than 0.05, which would mean you reject $H_0$. But what if the test statistic is less than 1.96? In that case you would reject $H_1$, but you already rejected $H_0$ from the P-value. Does one take precedence over the other, or would this never happen?

Comment: For example, for a right tailed test, p value is defined as $p = p(t) = \mathbb{P}(T > t | H_{0})$, where $T$ is the test statistic with known null distribution. When the distribution of the test statistic $T$ (when $H_0$ holds) is standard normal, it can be checked that $\mathbb{P}(T > 1.96) = 0.05$, and for this case $c_{0.05} = 1.96$ would be called a critical value. Naturally, the critical values may differ based on the null distribution of the test statistic (see, e.g., student's distribution). [See here for more examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value#General)

Comment: Possibly related: [Why do my p-values differ between logistic regression output, chi-squared test, and the confidence interval for the OR?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144603/7290)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They’re synonyms. The critical value is the value the test statistic has to reach in order for your hypothesis test to reject at your chosen level (maybe $0.05$, maybe not). If you are not getting these to agree, there is a bug in your code.

You might be stumbling on the fact that confidence intervals and hypothesis tests (usually) are inverses of one another. The p-value, it turns out, is the $\alpha$-level for which a $(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval has the null value as one of the endpoint.

Comment: Another possibility is confusion between a 1-sided and 2-sided test.

Comment: You can get differences if the test & construction of the CI are based on different methods (see: [Why do my p-values differ between logistic regression output, chi-squared test, and the confidence interval for the OR?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144603/7290)). It can be more common than you might expect.

Answer (score 8):

Hypothesis tests are always framed in terms of the null. In the case that the test statistic is less than the critical value, *then the null fails to be rejected*.  When test statistic exceeds the critical value, *we reject the null hypothesis*.

To your point, the p value could be less than 0.05 and we could still have the test statistic be less than the critical value.  This would mean our chosen $\alpha$ was smaller than 0.05, and would mean we would fail to reject the null.

Comment: But what if we chose $\alpha$ to be 0.05, and the p value was less than $\alpha$ *and* the test statistic was less than the critical value? You're saying that this would not be possible, and the only explanation is that the $\alpha$ value chosen was actually smaller? I guess what I'm really asking is what if the two "methods" (p value vs $\alpha$ and test statistic vs critical value) of rejecting $H_0$ contradict each other?

Comment: They can never contradict one another.  The p value is a function of the test statistic, the critical value is a function of alpha.  Your "two methods" are two sides of the same coin.

Comment: So it wouldn't matter which one of the "methods" I pick to reject $H_0$.

Comment: There are no methods to choose from. There is only one procedure.

Comment: I find this answer confusing. The answer seems to be saying that the two *can* contradict one another.

Comment: @JDL you can have a p value less than 0.05 and still fail to reject the null.  In that case, the associated tests' alpha value is less than 0.05.  For example, if I chose an alpha of 0.01, then a z test with such an alpha has a critical value of 2.57.  If my test yielded a test statistic of 2.3 my p value would be 0.021.  I would fail to reject the null because my p value is not smaller than 0.01 all the while having my p value smaller than 0.05

Comment: I see — but the question explicitly stated that alpha *was* 0.05.

Comment: @JDL your welcome to submit an answer you think is superior then.

Comment: I think Dave's answer covers it fine.