# Relative Risk P - Value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, biostatistics

Several sources indicate to use Z = lnRR/((SE)(lnRR)) to determine the P value for testing measurements of Relative Risk. I have been unable to find the origin of this approach. Is this an appropriate technique?

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the parentheses in what you wrote to mean:

$$Z=\frac{\ln RR}{\text{SE}(\ln RR)}, $$

where $\text{SE}$ is the standard error. This is a type of [Wald test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/wald-test/info), on a single coefficient.* Models of relative risk are typically fit in a log scale via [maximum-likelihood methods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/maximum-likelihood/info), for which theory indicates an asymptotic normal distribution of coefficient estimates. Testing that *z* value against a standard normal distribution provides the *p* value.

This is one of [3 types of test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/144608/28500) typically used with maximum-likelihood models. With small sample sizes a likelihood-ratio test for $\ln RR$ might be preferable, but that requires fitting two models, one with the predictor and one without. Wald tests on all coefficients are easily obtained from a single model fit, so those are what are usually reported in initial summaries of model results.

---

*Technically, a Wald test is based on a chi-square statistics and can evaluate multiple coefficients at once. With a single coefficient, the Wald test is equivalent to this *z*-test.